# Selenium test problem with dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-ide, impromptu

I wanna use **selenium** for testing my web app.

It works ... but ...

For the confirm dialog box I've rewrite the method

```
function confirm(text,cbk) {
                                $.prompt(text,{
                                    buttons:{Ok:true, Cancel:false},
                                    opacity: 0.3,
                                    overlayspeed: 'fast',
                                    promptspeed: 'slow',
                                    callback: function(v,m){
                                        if(v){
                                            cbk.call();
                                        }
                                        else{

                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
```

I was used **jquery** and the plugin **Impromptu** for the graphic of the confirm box.

I record my test with Selenium IDE.
After I start my test and the test fail.
The test is "*click in a link and should be appear the dialog box (impromptu style), and after that I wanna press key 'Ok'*"

This is the code of the test

```
<!-- login page -->
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/demoit/action/Home</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<!-- inser the username and the password -->
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>user_name</td>
    <td>tommaso</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>pass_word</td>
    <td>pwdtommaso</td>
</tr>
<!-- click in the login image that call a script for login -->
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=body &gt; div:nth(2) &gt; p &gt; img</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<!-- click on exit link -->
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=#mycontentheader &gt; table &gt; tbody &gt; tr:nth(1) &gt; td:nth(1) &gt; table.entrata &gt; tbody &gt; tr &gt; td &gt; a &gt; img</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertConfirmation</td>
    <td>Do you want to exit?</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>jqi_state0_buttonOk</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

That was produced by **Selenium IDE**.

What is the problem?

Please help me,

Regards,

Tommaso

Comment: Please show us the relevant selenium test code.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely to be a timing issue. You need to make selenium wait for the dialog box to appear before the `assertConfirmation`. Also I suspect that call is really only for genuine JS popups rather than jQuery style 'fake' popups that aren't really modal, so you should probably use a normal assert.

Comment: there are a lot of "Wait..." methods... what method do you suggest to me to use? thanks

Comment: WaitForElementPresent is usually a good one (sorry I'm more familiar with the Java bindings than HTML)

Comment: Just a doubt, when you look for an element and it doesn't exists on the page, isn't selenium automatically retrying once after performing a (very short) WaitForElementPresent internally? That would be a nice behavior, if that's the case you might just increase that timeout